# Cancel and restart dispatch_get_global_queue

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I am using `dispatch_get_global_queue` to performs some tasks in the background.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
  x=someNumber;
  [self dothis:x];
});

-(void)dothis:(int)x{
   for (int i=0,i<x,i++){
       // Some calculations
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           myTextview.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",x];
       });
   }
}
```

now as soon as my someNumber changes, I want to stop my `dispatch_get_global_queue` and restart it with the new `someNumber` value. Right now as soon as the `somenumber` value change and I call my `dispatch_get_global_queue` again, the old executions and new ones start to coincide sometimes, putting the wrong values in my textView.

Is there a way I can cancel and restart my execution with the new values?

Comment: No, you cannot achieve this functionality with Grand Central Dispatch.   You need to rethink your program logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` instead. They have more support for cancelling tasks once they've started.